# Language override in Manifest doesn't work

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm trying to translate some values in the XML Manifest of my Outlook Add-In but it seems to not work as expected.

```
<DefaultLocale>en</DefaultLocale>

<Description DefaultValue="Add-in to report suspicious emails.">
<Override Locale="fr-fr" Value="Complément pour signaler des emails malveillants." />
<Override Locale="fr-ca" Value="Complément pour signaler des emails malveillants." />
<Override Locale="fr" Value="Complément pour signaler des emails malveillants." />
<Override Locale="de-de" Value="Erweiterung zur Meldung verdächtiger E-Mails." />
<Override Locale="de-at" Value="Erweiterung zur Meldung verdächtiger E-Mails." />
<Override Locale="de-ch" Value="Erweiterung zur Meldung verdächtiger E-Mails." />
<Override Locale="de" Value="Erweiterung zur Meldung verdächtiger E-Mails." />
<Override Locale="es" Value="Extensión para reportar correos electrónicos sospechosos." />
<Override Locale="it" Value="Componente aggiuntivo per segnalare e-mail sospette." />
<Override Locale="pt" Value="Add-in para relatar e-mails suspeitos." />
<Override Locale="ru" Value="Надстройка для сообщения о подозрительных письмах." />
```

The only translation that works is for french language: Outlook clients configured in french languages have the translated version of the add-in but all non-english versions have the english version of the add-in instead of a version in their own language.

Do you have any idea of what is wrong?

I've the same issue with other translations:

```
<bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Report a suspicious email">
        <bt:Override Locale="fr-fr" Value="Signaler un email suspect" />
        <bt:Override Locale="fr-ca" Value="Signaler un email suspect" />
        <bt:Override Locale="fr" Value="Signaler un email suspect" />
        <bt:Override Locale="de-de" Value="Eine verdächtige E-Mail melden" />
        <bt:Override Locale="de-at" Value="Eine verdächtige E-Mail melden" />
        <bt:Override Locale="de-ch" Value="Eine verdächtige E-Mail melden" />
        <bt:Override Locale="de" Value="Eine verdächtige E-Mail melden" />
        <bt:Override Locale="es" Value="Informar un correo electrónico sospechoso" />
        <bt:Override Locale="it" Value="Segnala un'e-mail sospetta" />
        <bt:Override Locale="pt" Value="Denunciar um e-mail suspeito" />
        <bt:Override Locale="ru" Value="Сообщить о подозрительном письме" />
</bt:String>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: _Not familiar with the outlook-addin._ Officially country code should be capitals, fr-FR,  fr-CA, fr-CH. Also "de" would be sufficient, and for a deviating version: "de-AT" with "Eine gausige E-Mail melden". As only French works, it would seem that only the first Override is taken? Try commenting out all xx-yy. It might be they must come last.

Comment: Thanks for the post. Using just the language name alone is not supported across all combinations of Office client applications and platforms. 

Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/localization#examples

hence instead of "de","es", kindly use "de-de", "es-es". Kindly test it and let us know if it works or not.

Comment: In this case, it should be like 

<bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Report a suspicious email">
        <bt:Override Locale="fr-fr" Value="" />
        <bt:Override Locale="fr-ca" Value="" />
        <bt:Override Locale="de-de" Value="" />
        <bt:Override Locale="de-at" Value="" />
        <bt:Override Locale="de-ch" Value="" />
        <bt:Override Locale="es-es" Value="" />
        <bt:Override Locale="pt-br" Value="" />
        ...
</bt:String>

Comment: Thanks for your replies. In fact, I already tested with fr-fr, de-de, ... but it always translated to french when possible and let to the default for others.